# Can a Chaotic Pendulum be made Continuous?

Tags: kinematics, oscillators

Can a Chaotic Pendulum be made continuous? I mean, Is there any Method or any Arrangement for a chaotic pendulum to Oscillate forever? (never stop its motion)

Comment: the fact that it is chaotic has nothing to do with it stopping or not. If there is not friction it will not stop. Specificaly for the double pendulum, there are energies for wich it can behavie non-chaoticaly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research.

Comment: By mistake, I have rolled back an edited version by Qmechanic, which was more appropriate than first asked, please someone tell me how to delete the rollback?

Comment: Could the pendulum be used to generate energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chaotic pendulum, or for the matter, any pendulum, would go on forever if it were only under the influence of the gravitational force and not influenced by any non-conservative forces. (i.e. ones which dissipate the energy of the system, examples would be air drag and friction in common cases).

Also, any pendulum which is left initially at its lowest energy state (the bob at the bottom most part of its trajectory), it would stay that way forever. (Assuming no external forces.)